# Parse JSON using Regex in Google Sheet

Tags: json, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to parse JSON data using Regex. I want to get values of "name", "street", "lat" and "lon".
This formula to get their values:

- get name :

  =REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(JSON!$A$1,char(10)&"|"&char(34)&"|\s{2,}",""),"name:(.*?),street")
- get street :

  =REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(JSON!$A$1,char(10)&"|"&char(34)&"|\s{2,}",""),"street:(.*?)},location")
- get lan and lon:

  =REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(JSON!$A$1,char(10)&"|"&char(34)&"|\s{2,}",""),"lat:(.*?),lon")

  =REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(JSON!$A$1,char(10)&"|"&char(34)&"|\s{2,}",""),"lon:(.*?)},city")

**My problem**: i don't know to get the next data in column E until column L.

**My sheet**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QaCT0X8iw6OjfzrPXPTc-r_HNscHIOQl5N9BBJjaaaY/edit#gid=1163290419

Comment: When the values are retrieved from JSON object, I thought that to use the custom function created by Google Apps Script might be suitable. So I proposed it. But if that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that to use a custom function created by Google Apps Script might be suitable. So in this answer, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using the custom function.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Spreadsheet, and please put `=SAMPLE((JSON!$A1))` to a cell. By this, each value are parsed and put to each cell of a row.

```
const SAMPLE = value => [JSON.parse(value).result.flatMap(({place_info: {name, street}, location: {lat, lon}}) => [name, street, lat, lon])];
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- In your sample Spreadsheet, there are 2 `name2,street2,lat2,lon2`. I thought that 2nd one might be `name3,street3,lat3,lon3`.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot. i think that is so complicated if i use regex to parse the json data.

Comment: @d'natsu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.